# Incorrect date format in excel for imported data

Tags: excel, date

I'm importing set of records to excel which contains DATE field set in US format(mm/dd/yy). I have updated my windows settings to UK format(dd/mm/yy). Excel is able to convert date to UK format. But randomly for the same of data, I see dates in US format. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is just how excel works; it will try to convert dates by itself, or leave it as is if it cannot. e.g. 20/12/2019 is a valid UK date, but invalid US date. On a UK locale, it will get understood, but not on a US locale (and stays as text). Upon import, if you are using the wizard however, you should be able to pick the source date format, and Excel should convert from your specified format to the locale format.

Comment: How are you importing the data?  Usually, with an import operation, a wizard will open allowing you to specify the date format of the data to be imported.  Are you sure you are importing, and not just opening the file?  This problem has been asked and answered ad nauseum, so the specifics of why it isn't working for you depends on the specifics of exactly what you are doing.